# C# HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() dies when using Proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, httpwebrequest

I have the following code:

```
        HttpWebRequest request = createRequest("http://somesite", true);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        request.Proxy = new WebProxy("what:ever");

        string postData = "my data";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        using (var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Flush();
        }
```

When I ask VS to break on first-chance CLR exceptions, request.GetRequestStream() throws a NullReferenceException internally and then throws a System.Net.WebException (time out) exception to my code.

When I disable the proxy (works directly) it works.

It works just fine in my computer back home but not here (rented apartment, different internet connection).

I'm using the same settings on both machines.
Couldn't find anything on it.

Thanks.

Comment: Which proxy is it? Some of them have issues with large amounts of data, such as a file upload.

Comment: I set it in IE and manage to do whatever the code does my self. I even tried the same proxy on both computers, only 1 worked. It is relevant to say there is no kind of firewall in any end and I am set as the DMZ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, changing the implementation to use WebClient.UploadData seems to do the trick. Thank you.